# Composition of two multivariate functions

Tags: functions

Lets say I have 2 multivariate functions:

```
f(x,y) = x - y
g(x,y) = x + y
```

How do I get the composition of these 2 functions $g(f(x,y))$ ?

Comment: Both of these functions map $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R$  (I would guess) , so $g \circ f$ does not make sense, since the domain of $g$ is incompatible with the codomain of $f$.

Comment: $g(f(x,y))$ doesn’t make sense as the image of $f$ is $\mathbb R$ while the domain of $g$ is $\mathbb R^2$ providing your variables are real numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g(x,y)$ takes in $2$ arguments: $x$ and $y$. $f(x,y)$ is just one value, equal to $x-y$. Therefore, $g(f(x,y))$ doesn't make sense. However, $g(f(x,y,),0), g(0,f(x,y))$ etc. are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The composition $g(f(x,y))$ as you have written it is not well-defined, since $f:\mathbb R^2\mapsto\mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R^2\mapsto \mathbb R$.

Suppose we want to compose the functions $a:A\mapsto A'$ and $b:B\mapsto B'$. The composition $a\circ b$ is defined iff $B'\subset A$, and the composition $b\circ a$ is defined iff $A'\subset B$. Thus, you cannot compose two functions mapping $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$.

However, you might define composition in a different way to suit your needs; for example, you might consider $g(f(x,y),f(x,y))$.